# How to set text in one line vim

Tags: vim

Hi I'm working whith a big file, in this file there many logs, I want set log in one line, for example:

```
 log1: var{xd:title, se:1223, name: user, SO: win, country: XXX}
 log1: var{xd:title, se:1223, name: user, SO: win, country: XXX}
 log1: var{xd:title, se:1223, name: user, SO: win, country: XXX}
 log1: var{xd:title, se:1223, name: user, SO: win, country: XXX}
```

How I can set this text in one line using vim. I don't remember the sentence to make it.
Thanks at all.

Comment: Before and after example, please.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to join only these four lines then one option is:

```
 gg3J
```

If the goal is to join all the lines in a file one normal mode option is:

```
 :%j
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *fold* identical subsequent lines (to save space), you can use the following:

```
let &foldexpr = 'getline(v:lnum + 1) ==# getline(v:lnum) && v:lnum < line("$") ? 1 : (getline(v:lnum - 1) ==# getline(v:lnum) ? "<1" : 0)'
set foldmethod=expr
```